# Elegant way to create a circular permutation with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, permutation

I got a set of results like this:

```
| id |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
```

I'm trying to get

```
| id |
| 4  |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve this using an SQL script?

Comment: Can you provide other examples of how you would like to order the results, or describe it better? It's not clear what you are trying to do from this one example alone

Comment: are you suggesting that you would want 3,4,1,2 in some other iteration?

Comment: I'm simply trying to create a cyclic/circular permutation with an offset of 1 of the rows in the given table.

Comment: @Randy yes, another iteration of the script would give 3,4,1,2. Even better the offset parameter of the permutation would be specified as an input in the script.

Comment: without writing the sql - yes you should be able to create another logical column (boolean) for all numbers above and all below a target number, then sort on that column first, then your id to get this order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the mod operator, `%` to `ORDER BY`

```
DECLARE @maxId AS INT
SELECT @maxId = MAX(Id) FROM MyTable

SELECT id FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Id % @maxId
```

You can get further rotations by adding to Id, ie

```
ORDER BY (Id + 1) % @maxId
```

get you

```
3
4
1
2
```

Working SQL Fiddle (which I just found out exists)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7f15/5

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm + you can specify the offset parameter! I couldn't ask for more

Answer (score 0):

ok i'll take a stab at the SQL.

```
select case when id > 3 then 0
       else 1
       end
, id
from mytable
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and devoted time. @Bort solution seems more elegant though.